# How-to parse XML key:value pair

Tags: php, xml

I have a clients server returning the following (strange) XML response; how do I access each key:value pair?

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <response>
    <string key="__status">success</string>
    <string key="id">1000</string>
    <string key="mask">9999</string>
</response>';
```

I was hoping that the following would work, but it appears not.

```
$test = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo "Mask: " . $xml->response->mask; // Mask: 9999
```

Comment: You have to iterate over the `string` elements and access their text and their `key` attribute.

Comment: @Felix-Kling That's what I was thinking, just checking if there was an easier way. Is this structure of XML even well formed?

Comment: Yes it is. If you want a specific element, you can also use XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a specific element, you can use XPath:

```
$matches = $test->xpath('//string[@key="mask"]');
```

*(this requires PHP 5.2)*

This would give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [key] => mask
                )

            [0] => 9999
        )
)
```

If you want all elements, you have to iterate over all `string` elements and access their text and `key` attribute:

```
$items = array();

foreach($test->string as $item) {
    $items[(string) $item->attributes()->key] = (string) $item;
}
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [__status] => success
    [id] => 1000
    [mask] => 9999
)
```

Comment: check my answer. its more simple.

Comment: I am happy with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<pre>
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <response>
    <string key="__status">success</string>
    <string key="id">1000</string>
    <string key="mask">9999</string>
</response>';

$test = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo "Mask = ".$test->string[2];
?>
</pre>
```

Here is the working code.

Comment: Sorry, this won't work as I can't guarantee what order or even how many elements I will receive.

Comment: It solves this particular instance, but not the general problem.

Comment: But i was up to solve the syntax error in the OP's question. Anyways, the correct question by FELIX is much better.

Comment: Freak sorry for the vague-ness of the original question, I figured saying that the data coming from a clients server was good enough hint that the data may be in constant flux.

Comment: @Michael Pasqualone - No problem buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

if my memory server me right `simplexml` is extension. Are you sure you installed it? BTW, `simplexml` was added in PHP 5.0, so make sure you are not running lower version